# Which Version of neo4j Does the Grails Plugin Support?

Tags: grails, neo4j

Running the sample provided by [Puneet Behl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2618779/puneet-behl) at https://github.com/puneetbehl/neo4j-example against a new neo4j 4.3.1 database started via neo4j desktop.

config in application.yml changed to:

```
grails:
    neo4j:
        url: bolt://grails:grails@localhost:7687
        username: "grails"
        password: "grails"
        # type: embedded
        # location: build/data/neo4j
```

The application does connect to the db because when I omit the userid and password grails complains on startup.

I get the exception shown below when trying to load the pet controller.

The code it is referencing is the following:

```
    @Transactional
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond petService.list(params), model:[petCount: petService.count()]
    }
```

Am I using a too new version of neo4j?

```
| Running application...
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
2021-09-03 15:20:45.186 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : ClientException occurred when processing request: [GET] /pet/index
Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 2, column 8 (offset: 38))
" LIMIT {1}"
        ^. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
        at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 2, column 8 (offset: 38))
" LIMIT {1}"
        ^
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:143)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.blockingGet(InternalResult.java:128)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.hasNext(InternalResult.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.query.AbstractResultList.<init>(AbstractResultList.java:46)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.query.AbstractResultList.<init>(AbstractResultList.java:36)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.collection.Neo4jResultList.<init>(Neo4jResultList.groovy:57)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.engine.Neo4jQuery.executeQuery(Neo4jQuery.groovy:517)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.doList(Query.java:589)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.list(Query.java:568)
        at grails.gorm.PagedResultList.<init>(PagedResultList.java:43)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_list_closure2.doCall(DetachedCriteria.groovy:137)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_withPopulatedQuery_closure8.doCall(DetachedCriteria.groovy:771)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_withDatastoreSession_closure24.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:40)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withDatastoreSession(GormStaticApi.groovy:861)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.withPopulatedQuery(DetachedCriteria.groovy:742)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.list(DetachedCriteria.groovy:135)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
        at yellek.PetController.$tt__index(PetController.groovy:16)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause: null
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:80)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:107)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.unpackFailureMessage(CommonMessageReader.java:83)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.read(CommonMessageReader.java:59)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:47)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
                at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
                ... 1 common frames omitted

<===========--> 85% EXECUTING [20m 51s]
> :bootRun
```

Comment: It would seem that if I create a 3.5.29 version database that the code now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is here: https://github.com/grails/gorm-neo4j.
It only works with [Neo4j 3.x](https://github.com/grails/gorm-neo4j/blob/0812e0cd1061c0459c3588f5d5e38520ac3db5e0/gradle.properties#L20), hence the old parameter syntax (`{param}` instead of the newer `$param`).